# Complex shapes in SceneKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, 3d, scenekit

In SceneKit, a programmer may create a node/object by entering the following code:

```
SCNBox* box = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1 height:1 length:1 chamferRadius:0.1]; // define a geometry
SCNNode* boxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:box]; // make this geometry into a 3D node
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:boxNode]; // add the node into the scene
```

and you get a box node, measuring 1x1x1 units, with a 0.1 chamfer radius. It looks almost like a circle.

[image: box]

However, I want to render a more complex shape than a box, or a sphere, or a cylinder. For example, I want to render a puzzle piece onto the screen.

How would I go about doing that? I know it's possible by defining a `SCNShape` with a Bézier curve (in combination with `NSBezierCurve`). If I want to load a set of vertices into a geometry and have it be a material, how would I do that?

I'm new to 3D programming. I've messed around with spheres and simple shapes before. I might be going about making a puzzle piece render onto the screen in an incorrect fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently `Scene Kit` is only for rendering geometry and has very limited geometry generation tools, though the introduction of `Model I/O` seems to be the first step towards supporting more complex 3D modelling capabilities.

You are correct in that for simple shapes you can use `Scene Kit` basic geometries (box, sphere etc.) or an `SCNShape` with an `NSBezierCurve` for 3D extrusions with bevels and chamfers. For more complex geometries you have a couple of options:

**Third party 3D Modelling software** can be used to create the geometries and in some cases animations that can then be imported directly into `Scene Kit`. A lot of people seem to use Sketchup because it's free and easy to use. It's good for basic shapes but it is very limited in its capabilities. I'd advise using Blender, which is also free but has a lot more to create geometries and meshes and also allows you to create animations and materials that can be imported directly. It does have a steep learning curve but once you have it cracked it's a great asset to have.

This kind of software is best used for complex geometries such as levels, characters and scenery. It does have the downside of being rather un-dynamic once imported though, as every mesh will look the same, for example if you create a rock as a piece of scenery, you will need to create a lot of variations of the rocks, or have every rock in your game looking identical.

**Generate it in `Scene Kit`** by using `SCNGeometrySource` and `SCNGeometryElement` classes. These are essentially a series of points in 3D space (each an `SCNVector3`) that define the corners or vertices of your mesh. You then join them up into a mesh by putting your points into an array and defining which points should be joined together to make a triangle or element of your mesh. This is given as another array of `SCNVector3` vectors, where each part of the vector points to an index in the array of vertices. A Vector of [0, 1, 2] would create a triangle out of the points in the array indices 0, 1 and 2. There are [tutorials](http://ronnqvi.st/custom-scenekit-geometry) out there on how to do this.

The benefit of this is the ability to create random geometry, by creating a set of pseudorandom points and then combining them to create your mesh. From this you can then bake ambient occlusion using `Model I/O` (assuming Apple has fixed this, I've not checked) and continue to use `Model I/O` to create pretty realistic materials. The means you can effectively create whatever you'd like. Following on from the previous example, you can procedurally generate rocks that all look different from one another. You can use this to generate a near infinite number of puzzle piece possibilities.

As a side note, geometry and material are two different things in 3D modelling, and as you've just started you seem to have mixed them up in your question. A geometry is a mesh that defines the shape of an object, and a material defines how light interacts with that mesh to produce its final appearance. A geometry can have one or more materials attached to it to produce the result you want.

The option you choose is really down to what you want to achieve. For randomness the second choice is better, for quality the first choice is best.
I feel I'm waffling on a bit now so I'll end this here.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I have a friend that knows how to use Blender but I wanted to know if I could use SceneKit to generate models based on 3D points. I didn't know about the classes you mentioned; that'll help a lot! 